# Freemarker templates: How split large string in size of 34 using freemarker

Tags: split, freemarker

I would like to split a long string in size of 34 in freemarker template.

How could this be done with freemarker instruments?

Example:
String  - `"1234567890**A**234567890**B**234567890**C**234567890**D**234567890**E**234567890**F**234567890**G**234567890**H**234567890**I**234567890**J**234567890**K**234567890**L**234567890**M**234567890"` 
Range size - 34

Result should look like this -
`1234567890**A**234567890**B**234567890**C**234 567890**D**234567890**E**234567890**F**2345678 90**G**234567890**H**234567890**I**234567890**J**2 34567890**K**234567890**L**234567890**M**23456 7890`

Expecting
`1234567890**A**234567890**B**234567890**C**234 567890**D**234567890**E**234567890**F**2345678 90**G**234567890**H**234567890**I**234567890**J**2 34567890**K**234567890**L**234567890**M**23456 7890`

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to do that in freemarker, so it requires to use some workarounds to get the result.

```html
<#assign str = "1234567890**A**234567890**B**234567890**C**234567890**D**234567890**E**234567890**F**234567890**G**234567890**H**234567890**I**234567890**J**234567890**K**234567890**L**234567890**M**234567890">
<#assign str = "1234567890**A**234567890**B**234567890**C**234567890**D**234567890**E**234567890**F**234567">
<#assign range = 34 >

<#-- Use a 'for' loop as there is no 'while' loop in freemarker -->
<#list 0..1000 as idx>

    <#-- Break from the loop if there is no 'range' chars left in the string -->
    <#if (idx + 1) * range gt str?length><#break></#if>

    <#-- Print 'range' chars form the string -->
    ${str[(idx * range)..(idx * range + range - 1)]}
</#list>
```

Note that in your question, the example was a bit strange as the lines in the expected result are not 34 chars long.

Comment: I also want to display the remaining char in the string as well !
As the above query displays only the char which falls in the range of 34.

Comment: Also when the string length is less eg str = '123456789' and i want to make a chunk of size 6 then in the output i want ---  
123456
and the remaining char below in a new chunk but there should be only 4 chunks .
If the string size is more than after getting 4 chucks of the defined length it should truncate the remaining string data.